# Determination of radiation pressure

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure, radiation, classical-electrodynamics, density

Consider  the incidence of an electromagnetic wave on the plane $x=0$.

[image]

We have that:

$$f_x=\frac{dF}{dV}$$

$f_x$ is the volumic force density on the medium.

My doubt is purely mathematical. I want to the determinate the radiation pressure:

$$P_{rad}=\frac{F}{S}$$

I could say that:

$$\int_0^{\infty} f(x) dx=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dF}{dx.dy.dz}dx=$$

$$=\int_a^b \frac{dF}{dS}=$$

$$=\int_{P(0)}^{P(\infty)}dP_{rad} \hspace{15pt}?$$

As you can see on the second row I didn't chose the integral limits, because we have a integral upon two elementar variables.

So, is it correct to write $\frac{dF}{dS}=d\left(\frac{F}{S}\right)$?

---

**Note:** I have this question because I saw this solution written on a book and I know, for example, that $d(xy)=dx.y+dy.x\neq dx.dy$

Comment: I would consider the momentum of the incident radiation - this momentum is reversed (in reflection) or absorbed (in absorption) and this should tell you what $F\Delta t$ is. I don't understand your "volumetric force density on the medium" but I'm sure that $\frac{dF}{dS}\ne d\left(\frac{F}{S}\right)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The relation $\frac{dF}{dS}=d\left(\frac{F}{S}\right)$ is certainly **incorrect** as @Floris has mentioned in the comment. As the simplest counter-example, consider a linear function, $F(S) = \alpha \, S$, with $\alpha \neq 0$ as a proportionality constant. Then, one could easily see that
$$ \frac{dF}{dS}= \alpha \neq 0 = d\left(\frac{F}{S}\right) = d\left(\frac{\alpha S}{S}\right) = d \left( \alpha \right)~. $$
Notice that we have abused the notation above: on the left-hand-side, there is a **derivative** while on the right-hand-side, there is a **differential**; but for the moment, we neglect this abuse.

2) Furthermore, I cannot see what “volumic force density” is and why such a force, $f_x$, is relevant to this problem.
As far as I can understand, one should find the (normal) force per surface area (= pressure) exerted by the radiation on the surface $S$ on the $y-z$-plane (as in the posted figure). In the simplest case of a constant *normal* force $F$ the radiation pressure will be
$$ P = \frac{F}{S} ~.$$
The concise mathematical expression for a slightly more general case of a spatially varying force *normal* on a surface $A$ will be
$$ P \equiv \frac{d F}{d A} ~, $$
where $\mathcal{d}{A}$ is the **area** differential, and $\frac{d F}{d A}$ represents the **surface** force density, or the force exerted on an infinitesimal area $dA$. The infinitesimal area can be given in any coordinate system; for instance, in the case given above, using Cartesian coordinates, $d A  = d S = dy \, dz$.

For a more detailed discussion and more rigorous formulation, see < https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure#Formula >.